# How to make a multiple fetch request in ExpressJS and render data

Tags: node.js, express, fetch

I try to make a multiple API request with fetch in my ExpressJS route. This is the route which is working fine and I can log the data.

```
router.get('/api', async (req, res) => {
  Promise.all([
    fetch('https://boards-api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/hudl/jobs'),
    fetch('https://boards-api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/classpass/jobs')
  ]).then(function (responses) {
    // Get a JSON object from each of the responses
    return Promise.all(responses.map(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    }));
  }).then(function (data) {
    // Log the data to the console
    // You would do something with both sets of data here
    console.log(data);
  }).catch(function (error) {
    // if there's an error, log it
    console.log(error);
  }).then(function (err, data) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    return res.render('list', {
      data: listings,
    });
  })
});
```

Everything is working and I can log the data. Running now into the problem that I can return the data to the frontend so the last .then(function) is wrong. Can anybody help out here?